# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] cannot connect because the computer refused the connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to run a website in lavarel but I keep getting the error message. I have entered the correct password and username while the error occurs that the connection was refused by the computer.

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=''
DB_USERNAME=''
DB_PASSWORD=''        db, username and ps are filled in
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdNV.png)

Comment: Looks like the mysql Server is not started

Comment: you may check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-mysql-connection-error-sqlstatehy000-2002

Comment: I have used `sudo service mysql start` on the ubuntu mysql server and it still says the same @Jens

Comment: @BrianM is the Server started without any Errors?

Comment: I have added the status report in the image in the bottom of the post, it gave no errors @Jens